# `Too many levels of symbolic links` when installing linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic

Tags: 22.04

I'm getting a bunch of `Too many levels of symbolic links` when trying to install `linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic`.

I encountered this as part of an upgrade to 22.04 LTS.

```
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic (5.15.0-46.49) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic (5.15.0-46.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
cp: failed to access '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_fnyMFS//usr/sbin/reiserfsck': Too many levels of symbolic links
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_fnyMFS/sbin/reiserfsck': File exists
cp: failed to access '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_fnyMFS//usr/sbin/reiserfsck': Too many levels of symbolic links
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/reiserfsprogs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Maybe a circular set of links somewhere. Manually look at the problem, and what it links to, repeat etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any symlinks in the path: but there is an absolute path appearing in the middle of the path: `...fnyMFS//usr/sbin/...` --- maybe that's erroneous?

Comment: Well 22.04 did make /sbin  /bin  and /lib all simlinks, so maybe that is part of the issue.  I don't know anything about reiserfs.

Comment: Thanks! none of those dirs are symlinks on my installation at the moment.

Comment: Or did you mean all the files under sbin and bin symlinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt reinstall reiserfsprogs` seems to have fixed it.

Thanks EriC^^ on Libera.Chat's #ubuntu!

Comment: in my case the //usr/sbin/dmraid was another culprit to apt reinstall dmraid was due